# Why does request.allHTTPHeaderFields work when request.addValue and request.setValue both fail?

Tags: swift, session, url

I have been writing some code to make a call to an API that requires a key and secret key. I had been trying to set these keys in the header of `URLRequest` with `.addValue` and `.setValue`, but either way I got a response from the API that indicated that no keys had been set at all. However, when I use `.allHTTPHeaderFields` it just works no problem. I am curious why `.addValue` and `.setValue` both fail here...